# Getting files from server to my local pc using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a file in my godaddy server and I need to move that file to my local system. example: my remote location is 192.xxx.xxx.xxx/Infoware/Images and I need to move some Images from "Images" folder in my godaddy server to my local PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right, you just want to download a file.

Depending of the kind of Application you are trying to build, you can do that synchronously or asynchronously.

The difference is, that if you download the file **synchronously**, your program/thread will wait till the download has finished and then, continue.

If you download the file **asynchronously**, your program continues while downloading the file and you have to take care of when the download is finished. The advantage is, if you write a Windows Forms application, it stays reactive and you can update e.g. a progress bar.

For a console application that just downloads the file and is not required to report the progress, synchronous way is enough.

**Synchronous example:**

```
using System.Net;

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("http://example.com/myfile.txt", @"c:\myfile.txt");
```

**Asynchronous example:**

```
private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
  webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
  webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
  webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/myfile.txt"), @"c:\myfile.txt");
}

private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Download completed!");
}
```

Examples are from: http://www.csharp-examples.net/download-files/

Comment: Thanks alot, I got it.

Comment: I need to download a file which has first 7 characters as my admission No. I have some Images which has its first 7 chars as Admission no of student who has registered No I need to download a image of particular student. Please help me with this..

Comment: so you need to find out the exact filename first?

Comment: maybe you should use wget then. maybe this is relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117988/wget-with-wildcards-in-http-downloads